# How to group input data using spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

my spring batch job reads csv files from the folder(1 folder = 1 job, 1 folder = 1 unit of work). I need to read these data and enrich them using information from external endpoint. Obviously it is not a good idea to get information from external endpoint for each CSV row because application works with huge files. But anyway I need to execute several requests to remote endpoint but requests depends on CSV files content. Let's say where are column with name `merchantId`. For each `merchantId` I have to execute request to remote endpoint and enrich corresponding csv lines with data provided in response. So I need some tool in spring batch to collect all `merchantId`s and then find corresponding lines depends on `merchantId`

How could I do in spring batch? or maybe spring integration can help me somehow?

Comment: you want to call API for each Merchant ID or you want to call API for all Merchant IDs in a CSV one time?

Comment: for all Merchant IDs in all CSVs in the folder

Comment: Do we have a lot of Merchant IDs?

Comment: @Nghia Do, yes - we have a lot of Merchant IDs but count of CSV rows is much bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see as an extra step in your job to read only all those `merchantIds` into a `Set`. Call service for all of them and store the data somewhere in the `Map`. The next step could read those files again, obtain the merchant details by their `merchantId` from that `Map`. Not sure how is that effective from your source data perspective, but this way you definitely going to call external service only once.

Also I'm not sure that it is possible do not re-read those files again. Although you may suffer from out of memory error otherwise...

Comment: 1. Yes, I definitely don't want to reread large files again because of performance degradation. 2. Question about you solution: Where to put this map? I am afraid I can't use JobExecutionContext. I read somewhere that I can't store too big object in JobExecutionContext 3. I came up with a new idea - process csv file and for each line request remote endpoint but cache response. At this case I don't need reread files second time. But where to save this cache is still open question. I want to know your opinion about this idea ?

Comment: That `Map` could be as an output of the of the step we mention. So, no any entry in the job context. For the cache you can consider to use a cache abstraction from Spring Framework. Your service method should be marked with the `@Cachable` and every time your call that method with the same argument, the result is going to be obtained from the cache: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache

Comment: looks like a plan) I believe that there are exist feature that allows us to configure time of cache living

Comment: is it possible to make cache job scope? I want to have independent  cache for each job execution?

Comment: I think `cacheResolver` can solve your requirement.

Comment: from your link I understood that cacheResolver hekps to choose cachManager. I have no idea how it can help me

Comment: Well, that's not. See its API: `Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context);`. So, you would return job-specific `Cache` and it won't be available for other jobs. The `CacheOperationInvocationContext` could be used to determine a job specific `Cache`. I believe there is also something like `JobContext` in the `ThreadLocal` to deal with.